# Index data to elasticssearch cloud from Aws DynamoDB using java

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, elastic-cloud

I want to index the data from dynamo DB to elasticsearch cloud SAAS. My elasticsearch endpoint will be like

**elasticsearch endpoint URL**

**https://d9bc7cbca5ec49ea96a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:1234**

When ever if the CRUD operation happened in AWS dynamo db immediately it should get reflected in the index of elasticsearch cloud.

May i know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXmghnE1_vU

Comment: Hi link describes the creating stream from AWS dynamoDB to AWS elasticsearch service

Comment: But by Elasticsearch hosted environment will be in Azure so that i have mentioned the endpoint URL above

Comment: I need to stream the data from AWS dynamoDB to Elastic search hosted in my Azure cloud out of AWS environment

Comment: if you have appropriate permissions, you should be a able to use the same approach to write to azure as well right?

Comment: @bestwishes this is a whole tutorial on ES and DynamoDB. They speak at 19:27 https://youtu.be/WXmghnE1_vU?t=1167 about the connection between the two but they just kind of describe it, there aren't any policy docs or definitions. Also it seems like a very AWS specific solution, how would you use Lambda and Streams to put stuff in Azure? This https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/ is a lot more detailed and concrete but I'm not personally sure how to modify it to take the data out of AWS.

Comment: streams are database concept and people use it to sync multiple isolated data pieces, (PS even databases use streams to sync among themselves), you should use dynamodb stream and aws lambda. From AWS lambda use azure client to ingest data in azure ES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All thanks for all your support. I have attached the sample code it does the magic, I am able to index the data from dynamo db to elasticsearch both inside AWS and outside but we have to set a proper permission to lambda function as suggested in above comments.

```
package com.Firstlambda;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.ItemUtils;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.DynamodbEvent.DynamodbStreamRecord;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class HelloWorld implements RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, String> {
    private static String serviceName = "es";
    private static String region = "us-east-1";
    private static String aesEndpoint = ""
    private static String index = "";
    private static String type = "_doc";

    static final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();

    public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {
        for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : ddbEvent.getRecords()) {
            System.out.println("EventName : " + record.getEventName());
            System.out.println("EventName : " + record.getDynamodb());

            //AWS outside
            RestHighLevelClient esClient = esClient();
            //AWS outside

            //AWS Inside
            //RestHighLevelClient esClient = esClient(serviceName, region);
            //AWS Inside
            if (record.getEventName().toLowerCase().equals("insert")) {
                String JsonString = getJsonstring(record.getDynamodb().getNewImage());
                String JsonUniqueId = GetIdfromJsonString(JsonString);
                IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index, type, JsonUniqueId);
                indexRequest.source(JsonString, XContentType.JSON);
                try {
                    IndexResponse indexResponse = esClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
                    System.out.println(indexResponse.toString());
                    return "Successfully processed " + ddbEvent.getRecords().size() + " records.";
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else if (record.getEventName().toLowerCase().equals("modify")) {
                String JsonString = getJsonstring(record.getDynamodb().getNewImage());
                String JsonUniqueId = GetIdfromJsonString(JsonString);
                UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(index, type, JsonUniqueId);
                String jsonString = JsonString;
                request.doc(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);
                try {
                    UpdateResponse updateResponse = esClient.update(
                            request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
                    System.out.println(updateResponse.toString());
                    return "Successfully processed " + ddbEvent.getRecords().size() + " records.";
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("remove");
                System.out.println("KEYID : " + record.getDynamodb().getKeys().get("ID").getN());
                String deletedId = record.getDynamodb().getKeys().get("ID").getN();
                DeleteRequest request = new DeleteRequest(index, type, deletedId);
                try {
                    DeleteResponse deleteResponse = esClient.delete(
                            request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return "Successfullyprocessed";
    }

    public String getJsonstring(Map<String, AttributeValue> newIma) {
        String json = null;
        Map<String, AttributeValue> newImage = newIma;
        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, AttributeValue>>();
        listOfMaps.add(newImage);
        List<Item> itemList = ItemUtils.toItemList(listOfMaps);
        for (Item item : itemList) {
            json = item.toJSON();
        }
        return json;
    }

    public String GetIdfromJsonString(String Json) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(Json);
        return String.valueOf(jsonObj.getInt("ID"));
    }

    // Adds the interceptor to the ES REST client
//    public static RestHighLevelClient esClient(String serviceName, String region) {
//        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
//        signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
//        signer.setRegionName(region);
//        HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(serviceName, signer, credentialsProvider);
//        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(aesEndpoint)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(interceptor)));
//    }

    public static RestHighLevelClient esClient() {
        String host = "d9bc7cbca5ec49ea9gfde6a6ea683f70caca.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com";

        int port = 9200;

        String userName = "elastic";

        String password = "L4Nfnle3wxsfgjgLmV95lPiUb46hp";

        String protocol = "https";

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;
    }

}
```